# Iterate and set Class Attributes - Python Django

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to set class attributes outside of the `__init__` function, as a class attribute (rather than an instance attribute).

I want to do something like this:

```
class Trades():
    def __init__(self):
        for i in range(24):
            setattr(self, f'Hour_{i}', 0)
```

but for a django model, e.g. something like:

```
class Trades(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    Hour_0 = models.FloatField()
    Hour_1 = models.FloatField()
    for i in range(24):
        setattr(models.Model, f'Hour_{i}', models.FloatField())
```

But that doesn't work.

Is there another way I can iterate it, or do I have to manually assign each `Hour_X`  a `FloatField` ?

Comment: In your particular case I think doing it manually is your best bet. But if your concerns are related to _how to code is looking_, you can take look at [Writing custom model fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-model-fields/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python datamodel is not magical enough to allow what you're attempting here. You will have to manually assign those fields, since they are handled at class definition time by the [Model metaclass](https://github.com/django/django/blob/ce3351b9508896afdf87d11bd64fd6b5ad928228/django/db/models/base.py#L61), and it relies on model fields being defined declaratively on the *class*.

Your first approach fails because you can not set them on the instance.  Your second approach fails because you try to set attributes on the parent `models.Model` instead of on the class `Trades`.  Yet, you can't actually use the name `Trades` because the class is still under definition and so the name isn't bound yet.